# Checking if a list of objects contains a property with a specific value

Tags: c#, .net, list

Say I have the following code:

```
class SampleClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
List<SampleClass> myList = new List<SampleClass>();
//list is filled with objects
...
string nameToExtract = "test";
```

So my question is what List function can I use to extract from `myList` only the objects that have a Name property that matches my `nameToExtract` string.

I apologize in advance if this question is really simple/obvious.

Comment: The `Name` property in the `SampleClass` class should be of type `string` right?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.linq.enumerable#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) extension method:

```
var matches = myList.Where(p => p.Name == nameToExtract);
```

Returns an `IEnumerable<SampleClass>`. Assuming you want a filtered `List`, simply call `.ToList()` on the above.

---

By the way, if I were writing the code above today, I'd do the equality check differently, given the complexities of Unicode string handling:

```
var matches = myList.Where(p => String.Equals(p.Name, nameToExtract, StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
```

[See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-compare-strings)

Comment: Does this return all of the objects that match `nameToExtract`?

Comment: Specifically, all the objects whose `Name` property matches `nameToExtract`, yes.

Comment: thx - is there a boolean version whcih simply returns true or false if it does or doesn't exist?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Yes, that's the [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.linq.enumerable#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method.

Answer (score 26):

```
list.Any(x=>x.name==string)
```

Could check any name prop included by list.

Comment: This is the best solution for this question. Also because it's much better to read.

Comment: I think this answer may have missed the requirements of the question: the OP is asking how to produce _a new list_ that contains only those elements of the original list whose `Name` property matches a value. [The .Any() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) does not do that.

Answer (score 13):

```
myList.Where(item=>item.Name == nameToExtract)
```

Answer (score 5):

Further to the other answers suggesting LINQ, another alternative in this case would be to use the [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) instance method:

```
List<SampleClass> results = myList.FindAll(x => x.Name == nameToExtract);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;    
list.Where(x=> x.Name == nameToExtract);
```

Edit: misread question (now all matches)