# Checking if a property in a list of objects is equal for all items

Tags: c#, linq

This question is quite similar to [this C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651285/checking-if-a-list-of-objects-contains-a-property-with-a-specific-value), but rather than them all being equal to a particular known value, I want to know if they are all the same as each other no matter what that value is.

My list contains numerous objects such as:

```
public MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set;}
}
```

My initial approach was:

```
List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();
//... Add some values

string firstResult = MyList.First().MyProperty;
return MyList.All(x => x.MyProperty.Equals(firstResult))
```

But I feel there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I find it quite elegant!

Comment: That seems fine. You could do GroupBy and count the resulting groups, which might be overkill, or a basic foreach loop. "Elegant" isn't something we can really help with.

Comment: Another option would be `DistinctBy`:  `MyList.DistinctBy(x => x.MyProperty).Count() == 1`

Comment: Not sure how to phrase the question: Do you get a filled list _and then_ you need to check this? Or could you just track the property of each newly added entry, on adding? That shifts the "burden" to the add, but may spare you from iterating the whole list?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think a LINQ (or other) method such the one you are looking for does not exist. Have a look at [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) from Eric Lippert, former c# designer; No need to create such particular method when your two liner get the same result. Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is fine. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
var firstResult = MyList[0].MyProperty;
bool allSame = true;
foreach (var entry in MyList)
{
    if (!entry.MyProperty.Equals(firstResult)
    {
        allSame = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

...just with much less code.

In order to test that they all have the same value you need to know what *one* of the object's value is, which is why you'll always need to get the "first" value and use that as the comparison (though, obviously, it doesn't matter if it's the first, last, middle, etc, as long as it's an index that exists).

Depending on your need, you *could* use either GroupBy or DistinctBy. When you're dealing with Lists this is less of a concern, but if you're using regular `IEnumerable`s it means you need to compute the source multiple times.

```
var countOfMyProperties = MyList.GroupBy(x => x.MyProperty).Count();
// 1 = all the same
// >1 = not all the same
```

Using GroupBy allows you to ask the natural follow-up question "well, if not all of my objects have the same MyProperty value, how many distinct values are there (a "group"), and how many objects are in each group?"

Also, I'd recommend using `x.MyProperty == firstResult` rather than `x.MyProperty.Equals(firstResult)`, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought LINQ would have some sort of built-in system, but I guess not!

Comment: Why use == rather than .Equals()? I was always taught to use .Equals for strings, but this could of course be out of date

Comment: Additionally thanks for your extra note on IEnumerables, it's a factor I had not considered

Comment: I think you have a Java background. `==` and `.Equals()` are the same thing (mostly) in C#, and most people use `==` as the default for all comparison operations unless they specifically need something else.

Comment: Haha. I did indeed start with Java in university, now work with C# day to day. Guess it just stuck in my mind erroneously.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over

Answer (score 1):

(Just summing up, please give credit to the orginal answer ;-) )

In C#, you can use LINQ to check if all elements in a list have the same property value. Here are three different ways to do it:

1. **Using the `All` method:**

   The `All` method checks whether all elements in a collection satisfy a condition. In this case, the condition is that the property of each element is equal to the property of the first element.

   ```cs
   bool are_all_properties_same<T, TProp>(List<T> items, Func<T, TProp> propertySelector)
   {
       var first_property_value = propertySelector(items[0]);
       return items.All(item => propertySelector(item).Equals(first_property_value));
   }
   ```
2. **Using the `GroupBy` method:**

   The `GroupBy` method groups elements in a collection by a key. In this case, the key is the property of each element. If there is only one group, it means all properties are the same.

   ```cs
   bool are_all_properties_same<T, TProp>(List<T> items, Func<T, TProp> propertySelector)
   {
       return items.GroupBy(propertySelector).Count() == 1;
   }
   ```
3. **Using the `Distinct` method:**

   The `Distinct` method returns distinct elements from a collection. In this case, it returns distinct properties. If there is only one distinct property, it means all properties are the same.

   ```cs
   bool are_all_properties_same<T, TProp>(List<T> items, Func<T, TProp> propertySelector)
   {
       return items.Select(propertySelector).Distinct().Count() == 1;
   }
   ```

You can use these methods like this:

```cs
List<MyObject> myObjects = ...;
bool are_all_properties_same = are_all_properties_same(myObjects, myObject => myObject.MyProperty);
```

##### Keep in mind that *only* the 1. ("All") method stops at the first mismatch. The other two will go through the whole list!